# Automatic head in ms-word

Tags: microsoft-word, footers, title, head

I’m creating a template in word and would like to include a text field in the cover for the title, something like "Document Title", that will be replaced by the user with the real title the want to include.

Also would like that, once the user type its own title, this will be displayed in the head or footer automatically.

Is this possible with Word? I'm using Word for Mac in the Office 365 and can't find out the way.

Many thanks in advance.

Br

Answer (score 0):

If you create a specific style for the title on the cover (eg CoverTitle), you can then use a STYLEREF field in the header which will pick up the text which has that style applied (which should only be the title on the cover page).

As users can inadvertently delete paragraph marks (and therefore not use the style), I find it a good "safety feature" to insert a table row (without borders) and applying the CoverTitle style to the paragraph inside the table - less likely to delete that paragraph mark.